# Android and Detekt: Aligning .idea CodeStyle with detekt

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, code-formatting, detekt

I have an Android project that i've set up with [Detekt](https://github.com/detekt/detekt).

I'm currently using:

- `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.19.0` (Root build.gradle)
- `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.19.0` (in my modules).

Running `gradle detekt` works fine and it's correctly formats code in regards to ktlint rules and I've added logic to run detekt on compile successfully, with the built in ktlint rules in detekt-formatting. :)

My question is: I can't seem to find anything about how to align the auto formatting in Android Studio (Code > Reformat file), which, in my case, is set to be a specific one for my project `({root}/.idea/codeStyles/...)`, with the formatting used by Detekt.
Reason for wanting this, is that i now have to maintain two formatting style files and keep them aligned, instead of being able to make both formatters point to the same config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a straight forward way to do this, but got 2 good suggestions from one of the Detekt maintainers:

https://github.com/detekt/detekt/discussions/4663